# Parity for artificial dissipation term in a finite-difference solution

Tags: finite-difference, numerics

I have a doubt regarding the signal of the dissipative term in a finite difference solution for an equation of the form

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+f(x)=0, u(0)=0
$$

In which $f$ is an odd function and the solution (judging by the modelled phoenomena) should be an even function in a symmetric domain (say, $D=[-1; 1]$).

If I'm using the finite difference approximation

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\Delta_h u_i=\frac{u_i-u_{i-1}}{x_i-x_{i-1}}
$$

The second order Taylor series decomposition of $u_i$ and $u_{i-1}$ results in a dissipative term proportional to $\Delta x \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$. Thus I'm trying to solve the equation by defining the residual as

$$
r_i=\Delta_hu_i+f(x_i)+\alpha \Delta^2_hu_i \times \Delta x
$$

With $\alpha$ being a hyperparameter by which I can regulate how much artificial dissipation I want to apply.

I'm confused about the parity of the artificial dissipation term, however.
Without it, the residual is an odd function in $D$; however, if $u$ is an even function as I said above, $\Delta x \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ should also be one: therefore after it is added to the residual function to account for dissipation, the residual will not be odd when provided with an even $u$. In my specific case, this leads to $u$ converging to a physically impossible, uneven funcion after some Newton iterations when $\alpha\neq 0$.

Am I getting the idea of the dissipation term wrong?

Comment: You claim you use finite differences, but you don't have a boundary value problem, as you have only one condition at $0$.

Comment: @VoB I think he is considering periodic BCs. Then $u(0)=0$ is sufficient.

Comment: @Pedro Secchi You mentioned a symmetric domain. Do you use periodic BCs?

Comment: Hi, yes, as I mentioned above I’m using u(0)=0 as a boundary condition. I’m not using a periodic BC, however. The problem I’m trying to model is the boundary layer over a symmetric airfoil, the thickness of which is supposed to be an even function. The equation is not exactly formatted as the one above (would have to add a function multiplying the derivative term which I kept out of the question for simplicity), but the mathematical considerations I made above regarding the signal are still valid

Comment: PS the boundary layer problem is not supposed to be periodic. Is the u(0)=0 BC still not enough then? I thought it would be enough to close the system

Comment: @PedroSecchi finite differences work usually with a condition at the initial and one at the final point. If that's not the case, how can you define a value when you're close at the boundary? Let's say you have $M$ points, and you need the derivative at $x=M$: then you have (using order 1 approximation) $$\frac{u_{M}-u_{M-1}}{ \Delta x}$$, but you don't know what's the value for $u_{M}$.

Comment: I understand that you have as domain $D=[-1,1]$. Then, by physical considerations, you state that you can work on $\tilde{D}=[0,1]$, and you have the value for $u$ at $x=0$ (so that's the *first* boundary condition). What about the one at $x=1$? @PedroSecchi

Comment: @VoB I’m working with a first order differential equation with a single variable. $f(x)$ above is known. In my actual problem (without the simplifications I made in order to explain it here), I’d have $f(u, x)$, making it a non-linear first order equation, but that doesn’t change the fact that a single boundary condition would be enough to get a solution. Does adding the second order, artificial dissipation term imply I’d need one more BC? That also doesn’t change the fact that the parity of the second order term is opposite to the first order term, however, so my doubt remains...

Comment: Well, if the equation is $u'(x)=f(u(x),x)$ , with the condition $u(0)=u_0$, then it's an ODE an you need just the **initial condition**. It's a bit misleading, IHMO, to call it "boundary" condition. For ODEs one does not use finite differences, but time integration methods, like explicit/implicit euler or others. 

For instance, you could use $$u_{i+1} = u_{i} + \Delta x f(x_{i+1},u_{i+1}$$ with $u_0 = 0$. The question is up to which time you want to integrate @PedroSecchi

Answer (score 3):

I think you can understand this using the concept of a modified equation. As you have shown, your discretization

$$
\frac{u_i - u_{i-1}}{h} + f(x) = 0 
$$

is an approximation of your differential equation $u_x + f(x) = 0$ with accuracy $\mathcal{O}(h)$. Now consider the Taylor expansion of your exact solution

$$
u(x_{i-1}) = u(x_i) - h u_x(x_i) + \frac{1}{2} h^2 u_{xx}(x_i) + \mathcal{O}(h^3)
$$

and plug it into your finite difference approximation. This results in

$$
u_x(x_i) + f(x) + \frac{h}{2} u_{xx}(x_i) + \mathcal{O}(h^2) = 0
$$

Therefore, while your approximation is an $\mathcal{O}(h)$ approximation of your original differential equation, it is an $\mathcal{O}(h^2)$ (that is: more accurate!) approximation to the modified differential equation

$$
u_x + \frac{h}{2} u_{xx} + f(x) = 0
$$

Note that in the limit $h \to 0$, both become identical but for every finite $h$ they will be different. Using https://www.wolframalpha.com/, we can solve the modified equation for the case $f(x) = 1$ to illustrate the effect this has. The solution is

$$
u(x) = c_1 \frac{h}{2} \exp(-\frac{2 x}{h}) - x + c_2 = 0
$$

Note that if $h = 0$, you get $u(x) = -x + c_2$ which is the correct solution to $u_x + 1 = 0$. Your boundary condition $u(0) = 0$ alone is not enough to fix both $c_1$ and $c_2$ - thus, your scheme will somehow implicitly fix a second BC, I am not sure how. But unless it is precisely in a way that $c_1 = 0$, your actual solution will look like what is shown in the figure. [image]

Note how the exponential term makes it a non-even function (neither is it odd). So while your exact solution in the limit $h\to0$ is even, your numerical scheme does not replicate this property for finite mesh sizes $h > 0$.